# how to remove a user from Queue with apex program

Tags: user, queue

I need to remove a User from a queue through Apex. I tried to insert and delete a User from a queue. While inserting there was no issue, but there was an issue in removing user from queue.

> System.ListException: Missing id at index: 0

```
list<GroupMember> DeleteGroupMemberRecord = New list<GroupMember>();
  for(QueueMember qm:RemoveQueueMemberList){
    for(Group g:GroupList){
      GroupMember member = new GroupMember();
      member.UserOrGroupId = qm.UserOrGroupId;
      member.GroupId =g.id;
      DeleteGroupMemberRecord.add(member);
    }
  }

  System.debug('Deleted Queue members--  '+DeleteGroupMemberRecord); 
  System.debug('Deleted Queue members size--  '+DeleteGroupMemberRecord.size());

 if(DeleteGroupMemberRecord!=NULL && DeleteGroupMemberRecord.Size()>0) {
   delete DeleteGroupMemberRecord;
 }
```

Comment: What part of your code is working ?

Comment: |System.ListException: Missing id at index: 0

Comment: Please don't describe what went wrong by saying "there was an issue." This type of question is likely to be closed because it lacks the information we need to help you. Be specific! ***What went wrong?***

Comment: thanx for ur response i got this error

Comment: you are constructing `member` and never populating its `id` field - hence, the delete fails; as an aside, your lists should have plural variable names or be suffixed by `List`; aside#2 - the test for `if(DeleteGroupMemberRecord!=NULL && DeleteGroupMemberRecord.Size()>0)` is superfluous and should be omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's possible for this error to occur based on that code.

This is where it will be triggered:

```
if(DeleteGroupMemberRecord!=NULL && DeleteGroupMemberRecord.Size()>0) {
  delete DeleteGroupMemberRecord;
}
```

You are performing a delete of the list of records in your `DeleteGroupMemberRecord`. If you have items that don't have an id in the list, you will get the `System.ListException: Missing id at index: 0` error.

What you will have to do is retrieve all the `GroupMember` objects (probably via a query) that you want to delete before deleting them.

Perhaps the query could look for `GroupMembers` containing these characteristics?

```
GroupMember[] gms = [SELECT Id, Name 
                     FROM GroupMember
                     WHERE UserOrGroupId = :qm.UserOrGroupId
                       AND GroupId = :g.id];
```